# Apply Python function to one pandas column and apply the output to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

Hello Community,

I have read so many answers and blogs yet I am not able to figure out what simple thing I am missing out!. I am using 'conditions' function to define all the conditions and apply it to one dataframe column. And if the condition satisfies, it should create/update 2 new dataframe columns 'cat' and 'subcat'.

It would be a big help if you guys can help me out here!

```
dict = {'remark':['NA','NA','Category1','Category2','Category3'],
        'desc':['Present','Present','NA','Present','NA']
} 

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Dataframe looks something like this:

```
          remark       desc
0         NA           Present      
1         NA           Present        
2         Category1    NA                   
3         Category2    Present                   
4         Category3    NA
```

I have written a function to define conditions as below:

```
def conditions(s):

    if (s == 'Category1'):
        x = 'insufficient'
        y = 'resolution'
    elif (s=='Category2):
        x= 'insufficient'
        y= 'information'
    elif (s=='Category3):
        x= 'Duplicate'
        y= 'ID repeated'
    else:
        x= 'NA'
        y= 'NA'
    
    return (x,y)
```

I have multiple ideas to execute the above function on the dataframe column but no luck.

```
df[['cat','subcat']] = df['remark'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([conditions(df)[0],conditions(df)[1]]))
```

My expected dataframe should look something like this:

```
          remark       desc        cat           subcat
0         NA           Present     NA            NA      
1         NA           Present     NA            NA
2         Category1    NA          insufficient  resolution         
3         Category2    Present     insufficient  information              
4         Category3    NA          Duplicate     ID repeated
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way around this is with a list comprehension :

```
df[['cat', 'subcat']] = [("insufficient", "resolution")  if word == "Category1" else 
                         ("insufficient", "information") if word == "Category2" else
                         ("Duplicate", "ID repeated")    if word == "Category3" else 
                         ("NA", "NA")
                         for word in df.remark]

  remark      desc               cat         subcat
0   NA        Present          NA              NA
1   NA        Present          NA              NA
2   Category1   NA          insufficient    resolution
3   Category2   Present     insufficient    information
4   Category3   NA          Duplicate       ID repeated
```

@dm2's answer shows how to pull it off with your function. The first `apply(conditions)` creates a series containing tuples, the second `apply` creates individual columns, forming a dataframe that you can then assign to `cat` and `subcat`.

The reason why I suggest a list comprehension is because, one you are dealing with Strings, and in Pandas, working with strings via vanilla python is more often than not faster. Also, with the list comprehension the processing is done once, you do not need to apply the conditions function and then call `pd.Series`. That gives you a faster speed. Testing will assert or debunk this.

Comment: I like your list comprehension idea. I tried the same earlier but since the column ('cat '&'subcat') is not present in the df. it gives 'KeyError'. Any idea?  
KeyError: "None of [Index(['cat', 'subcat'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Comment: Yup using timeit this is way, WAY faster: mean of 7 runs of 1000 tries for my code is 0.3s,  your code runs the same in 0.009s.

Comment: i'm not sure why you have that error @nealkaps - the code above should create two new columns. If you are using a notebook, you could restart the kernel and run the cell again.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
 df[['cat','subcat']] = df['remark'].apply(conditions).apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
  remark      desc               cat         subcat
0   NA        Present          NA              NA
1   NA        Present          NA              NA
2   Category1   NA          insufficient    resolution
3   Category2   Present     insufficient    information
4   Category3   NA          Duplicate       ID repeated
```

Edit: This might be the simpler way to apply your function that you already have, but in case you have a huge DataFrame, for faster code check out the answer by @sammywemmy using list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the entire `dataframe` where you just need to pass the lambda variable (`x`).

```
df[['cat','subcat']] = df['remark'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([*conditions(x)]))
```

`*` on iterables can `unpack` them so you don't need to call the same function twice to extract output. Perhaps the compiler resolves this but I don't think so...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `series.replace` with a mapping dictionary

```
df['cat'] = df.remark.replace({'Category1': 'insufficient',
    'Category2': 'insufficient', 'Category3': 'Duplicate'})
df['subcat'] = df.remark.replace({'Category1': 'resolution',
    'Category2': 'information', 'Category3': 'ID repeated'})

print(df)
      remark     desc           cat       subcat
0         NA  Present            NA           NA
1         NA  Present            NA           NA
2  Category1       NA  insufficient   resolution
3  Category2  Present  insufficient  information
4  Category3       NA     Duplicate  ID repeated
```